# Finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $f(x)=(x^3-2x)^{inx}$

Tags: calculus

This is the function:

> $$f(x)=(x^3-2x)^{inx}$$

Is it possible for me to solve the problem with chain rule? Or there's  another approach for this question?

the answer is $$(x^3-2x)^{inx}\left[\frac{3x^2-2}{x^3-2x}inx+\frac{1}{x}in(x^3-2x)\right]$$

which is given by my textbook

I have try two ways to slove this question, one is use the chain rules, another is let the function turn into to be in first. **However, neither of the answer fit the answer of the textbook.**

Here's my answer:

1)Let the function in first

$iny=inxin(x^3-2x)$

$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}in(x^3-2x)+inx\frac{1}{x^3-2x}(3x^2-2)$

$inx(\frac{1}{x}in(x^2-2)+\frac{3x^2-2}{x^3-2x}$

---

2)by chain rules
let$f(x)=p^{inx}$

let$g(x)=x^3-2x$

Rewrite the sentence into $\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x)))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

it appear $(x^3-2x)^{inx}in(x^3-2x)\frac{1}{x}(3x^2-2)$

Comment: When you wrote "inx" did you mean the natural logarithm of x?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is best to write it in a different form first.

$f(x)=(x^3-2x)^{inx}=\exp( inx \log (x^3-2x))$ and then use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the natural logarithm gives

$$ f(x)=(x^3-2x)^{inx} \implies \ln(f(x))=inx\ln( x^3 -2x )$$

$$\implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{d}{dx}( inx )\ln( x^3 -2x ) \implies f'(x)=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}( inx )\ln( x^3 -2x )  $$

$$ \implies f'(x)=(x^3-2x)\frac{d}{dx}( inx )\ln( x^3 -2x ). $$

I think You can work out the rest.